# Simulate MS Word functionality in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rich-text-editor, word-processor

I need to implement a document editor similar to Google Docs or Microsoft Sky Drive (with the possibility to have N pages, page settings, export to word...). A great component would be this one: http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#RichTextBox/MSWord, but it's for Silverlight, I need the exactly component for an asp.net mvc application.

I have found different wysiwyg html editors, but this is not a solution for the problem of multiple pages.

Comment: What do you mean with multiple pages??

Comment: means...to have N text areas representing pages. to "simulate" in a way the behavior of ms word. similar to editing a document in google docs.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly need the breadth of features found in Word or Google Docs, consider using Word or Google Docs.  Google docs has [Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) and Office 365 has an extensive [development platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj984338.aspx).

If not, and something more mundane can fit your needs, consider using an existing non-paging editor, then render to a PDL (PDF or other) and add paging on output.

Keep in mind, you can embed Silverlight in MVC4, so the component you referenced is not necessarily unsuitable.  (See [this msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jowardel/archive/2009/03/09/asp-net-mvc-silverlight.aspx) and [this non-ms one](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/02/09/silverlight-as-a-view-in-aspnet-mvc.aspx) for examples of how to do so)

Answer (score 1):

As I know there no simple solution for you. You can see it in [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750468/rich-text-editorwysiwyg-with-paging-using-javascript).

You have to implement own editor or extend the functionality of existed editor. I recommend you don't load entire document but show only current page (+3 and -3) and count of pages. And add extra information via Ajax.

BTW you will need a library for creating word document - I recommend you to use [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124). And how to work with this - [Creating Documents by Using the Open XML Format SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd440953%28v=office.12%29.aspx)